# NSCollectionView: Go to the next view on selection with Selected Item

Tags: xcode, macos, nscollectionview

I am new to OS X and have started dealing with NSCollectionView. What I am trying to do is to take show NSCollectionView with array of imageView an labels. And on the selection of the image I want to open a new viewController class. I am able to show array of images and labels in collection view but I am completely lost on how to go to new view with the selection made in NSCollectionView and how to show the image selected to the new viewController class.

I am having an NSTabView and in that I am having customView in which I am showing CollectionView. And in awakeFromNib I am doing this to populate my collectionView

```
  -(void)awakeFromNib
{
arrItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
 NSMutableArray *imageArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Baby-Girl-Wallpaper-2012-7.jpg",@"Cute-Little-Baby-Girl.jpg",@"Joker_HD_Wallpaper_by_RiddleMeThisJoker.jpg",@"The-Dark-Angel-Wallpaper-HD.jpg",@"hd-wallpapers-1080p_hdwallpapersarena_dot_com.jpg",@"lion_hd_wallpaper.jpg",@"Ganesh_painting.jpg",@"krishna-wallpaper.jpg",@"LeoN_userpic_79630_fire_lion_by_alex_barrera.jpg",@"273483.png",@"japan_digital_nature-wide.jpg", nil];
NSMutableArray *imageName = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Baby-Girl",@"Cute-Little",@"Joker",@"The-Dark",@"hd-wallpapers", @"lion", @"Ganesh", @"krishna", @"LeoN_userpic",@"273483.png",@"japan_digital", nil];

for(int i = 0; i<[imageArray count]; i++)
{
    STImageCollectionModal * img1 = [[STImageCollectionModal alloc] init];
    img1.image = [NSImage imageNamed:[imageArray objectAtIndex:i]];
    img1.imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[imageName objectAtIndex:i]];
    [arrItems addObject:img1];
}
[collectionView setContent:arrItems];
}
```

Later I created a new class named "STCollectionView" subclass of NSCollectionView and assigned the collectionView class to "STCollectionView" and with the help of setSelectionIndexes method I tried getting the index of the selected item by this

```
  - (void)setSelectionIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)indexes
 NSLog(@"%ld",[indexes firstIndex]);
```

But this method is getting called twice and whenever i put "super setSelectionIndexes" it gives me garbage value.
I am searching it all over but unable to find any kind of solution. Please help..

Thank you in advance.

Comment: is your collectionview got selected ?

Answer (score -2):

Your question is confusing me.What i am thinking you can do this task simply by adding UICollectionView and in `UICollectionView` add custom `UICollectionViewCell`.In custom UICollectionViewCell add `UIImageView` and `UILabel`.
in the method

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString *identifier = @"ReuseID";
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imagewithNmaed:@"your Image name"];
    cell.label.text = @"image Named";
return cell;
  }
```

and in storyBoard hold CLT+drag to your `UIViewController`.In the method prepareForSgue Method pass data to your Next viewController.

Comment: I am working on OS X and not on IOS. I know how to handle UICollectionView in ios but in OS X i.e is Mac App I don't know how to handle NSCollectionView.